# How to detect UNICODE characters when trapping WM_CHAR messages?

Tags: c, winapi

So, my window procedure is currently trapping all WM_CHAR messages, it works fine with ASCII characters but when I try something like:

```
case 'ф':
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Ф detected"), TEXT("key"), MB_OK);
```

it fails for some reason.

What's wrong with my approach and how do I fix this?

**EDIT**: source-code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     switch (message)
     {

          case WM_CHAR:
               switch(wParam)
               {

                  case '3':
                    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("'3' was pressed"), TEXT("key detected"), MB_OK);
                    return 0;
                  case 'ф':
                    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT( "ф was pressed"), TEXT("key detected"), MB_OK);
                    return 0;


                  default:
                      return 0;
               }

          case WM_DESTROY :
               PostQuitMessage (0) ;
               return 0 ;


     }
     return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `L'ф'`? Are you sure `UNICODE` is `define`d before including WinAPI headers and you're not using `RegisterClassA()` instead of `RegisterClassW()`?

Comment: @Swordfish I tried that already. Funny thing is I just used the *IsWindowUnicode* function and apparently *UNICODE* is not defined in my system

Comment: Visual Studio? Project Properties *~>* Configuration Properties *~>* General *~>* Character Set: Use Unicode Character Set.

Comment: @Swordfish I'm compiling directly via the command prompt with CL

Comment: `#define UNICODE` before including WinAPI headers, or compile with `/DUNICODE`. To make absolutely sure you don't get an ANSI-Window use `RegisterClassW()` to register its window class.

Comment: @Swordfish  **IsWindowUnicode** works now, but i'm still unable to detect unicode characters in the switch statement

Comment: can you try with `0x0424` instead of `L'ф'` ? If that doesn't work, try to log the value you actually get.

Comment: @Trey Would you please show your Message Pump and WindowProc?

Comment: @huysentruitw   case 0x0444 solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: Tells you that the compiler doesn't know that you're talking Russian.  Not unusual on a German machine.  Configure your text editor to save the source file in UTF8 with a BOM.

Comment: Or, tell the compiler what you are doing. It's a fundamental requirement for a program to read a text file with the character encoding it was written with. [`/source-charset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/source-charset-set-source-character-set?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-Unicode characters need to be replace as Unicode characters in `switch-case`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     switch (message)
     {

          case WM_CHAR:
               switch(wParam)
               {

                  case L'3':
                    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("'3' was pressed"), TEXT("key detected"), MB_OK);
                    return 0;
                  case L'ф':
                    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT( "ф was pressed"), TEXT("key detected"), MB_OK);
                    return 0;


                  default:
                      return 0;
               }

          case WM_DESTROY :
               PostQuitMessage (0) ;
               return 0 ;


     }
     return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

The values of `'ф'` and `L'ф'` are different. The values of `'ф'` and other characters not in the ASCII table are often resolved to `'?'` (63)